# java generate random numbers between range of 30 and 32 digits

Tags: java

Reading other posts I have figured I will have to use BigInteger to generate 20,000 random numbers between the range of 30 and 32 digits.

```
public BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd)
```

But this does not allow minimum and maximum range for a number.

Thanks

Comment: A simple solution would be to randomly choose between `30`, `31`, and `32` each time you want to generate a number.

Comment: Do the 20000 numbers have to be unique?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen You would have to use a weighted random number: There are 10 times as many 31 digit numbers as 30 digit numbers.

Comment: What is the purpose of passing in a `Random` instance? Why it that a requirement? And what is the meaning of `numBits`?

Comment: yes 20000 numbers have to be unique

Comment: @Bohemian `numBits` is how many bits the randomly generated number should contain, and the `Random` instance is the random number generator to generate that n-bit number

Comment: @HunterMcMillen (Wow. His lips didn't even move...) I want to know why then the question title says "between 30-32 digits" - that is enough to know the number of bits. Also, for any number of bits, `1` is a valid random number but it has only 1 digit. Is the number of digits actually relevant?

Comment: @Bohemian I imagine he wants to generate numbers in that range of digits. At least that is what it appears from his question. Your initially question didn't mention digits at all, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Bohemian: as far as I understand the OP wants to know how to construct a random number in the range 1e29 and 1e32-1 (i.e. 100000000000000000000000000000 and 99999999999999999999999999999999 using the standard java constructor for [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(int,%20java.util.Random))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use this function, you can do

```
public static BigInteger random(Random rand, BigInteger minValue, BigInteger maxValue) {
    BigInteger range = maxValue.subtract(minValue).add(BigInteger.ONE);
    int bits = range.bitLength();
    BigInteger ret;
    do {
        ret = new BigInteger(bits, rand);
    } while(ret.compareTo(range) >= 0);
    return ret.add(minValue);
}
```

Comment: Just wondering whether instead of the loop `ret.mod(range).add(minValue)` would be better performance wise than possibly doing more than one call to the RNG.

Comment: This is possible if you generate a few more bits so that the result is not skewed (so each number has a reasonable equal chance)  You would have to benchmark it to see which is faster.